# CNContactViewController can't call or send a message (show using Peek and Pop or UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm showing `CNContactViewController` in my application using Peek and Pop, it looks ok, but none of actions is working.

Here is my code. Creating the View Controller:

```
func previewViewController() -> CNContactViewController {
    let contactVC = CNContactViewController(for: theContact)
    contactVC.allowsEditing = false
    contactVC.allowsActions = true
    contactVC.delegate = defaultContactVCDelegate
    return contactVC
}
```

Implementing the `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate`:

```
extension MyViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing,
                     viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        let preview = previewViewController()
        let wrapper = UINavigationController(rootViewController: preview)
        return wrapper
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing,
                     commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) 
    {
        guard let wrapper = viewControllerToCommit as? UINavigationController else { return }
        guard let preview = wrapper.viewControllers.first else { return }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(preview, animated: false)
    }
}
```

The `CNContactViewControllerDelegate`:

```
class DefaultContactViewControllerDelegate: NSObject, CNContactViewControllerDelegate {
    func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController,
                         shouldPerformDefaultActionFor property: CNContactProperty) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

I suppose if these actions are present on the screen (I mean bottom actions and top circles), they are supposed to be touchable. But when I touch them, nothing happens, as if user interaction where disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as it often happens, the solution came up to me before I received an answer.

The problem was that `CNContactViewController` was somehow broken after previewing in `previewingContext(,viewControllerForLocation)` method.

So I just create and show a new controller for the same `CNContact` instead of using `viewControllerToCommit`.

Here is my working codepiece:

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing,
                 commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) 
{
    let preview = previewViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(preview, animated: false)
}
```